# amcl and global map question

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
**** static map *****
image: rosmap.pgm
resolution: 0.005
origin: [0, 0, 0]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196
width:        20.0
height:       20.0

*** common map parms ****
obstacle_range:         2.5
raytrace_range:         3.0
footprint:              [[0.25, 0.1], [0.25, -0.1], [-0.25,-0.1], [-0.25, 0.1]] 
max_scaling_factor:     0.02  # The scalling factor for footprint defined in local costmap
inflation_radius:       0.02 # Propagating cost values out from occupied cells that decrease with distance.
map_type:               costmap
track_unknown_space:    true
observation_sources:    laser_scan_sensor 
laser_scan_sensor:      {sensor_frame: hokuyo_frame, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
resolution:             0.005


global_costmap:
  global_frame:        /map
  robot_base_frame:    /base_link
  update_frequency:    30.0
  publish_frequency:   30.0
  static_map:          true
  width:               20.0
  height:              20.0     

local_costmap:
  global_frame:      /odom
  robot_base_frame:  /base_link
  update_frequency:  30.0
  publish_frequency: 30.0
  static_map:        false
  rolling_window:    true
  width:             16.0
  height:            16.0
```

I running amcl and move_base with no static map. The map on setting position looks like. Should not the local map be contained fully within the global map. How do I get them to center on each other?

[image: image description].

if I set a goal that does not over lap the two then I get his message.

```
[ WARN] [1382396905.755665136, 26.606000000]: The goal sent to the navfn planner is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail to this goal.
```

Why does the global map not overlap the local cost map? How can I get them to align. The global map should map on top of the grid.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92966/amcl-and-global-map-question/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a bad origin setting in the  map yaml file

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0